# Find uniqueidentifier in varbinary

Tags: sql

I am pretty weak on sql, but have been tasked with fixing existing functionality. Basically there are numerous uniqueidentifiers which have been stored in a varbinary(max) and I want to pull out the appropriate one. I have tried 
`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
CONVERT(varbinary,[fieldId]) IN (fieldvarBinary)`
Along with a few other simple queries - but nothing seems to be pulling back the appropriate records. Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: Example data from field - `0x4B9E33FF49A41F4290C51298E20A8515`

Comment: Can you show us examples of data in those fields already?

Comment: "Basically there are numerous uniqueidentifiers which have been stored in a varbinary(max) " - oh gawd!......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

Since each uniqueidentifier (GUID) is a fixed 16 bytes in length, write a table-valued function that breaks the varbinary up into a table of 16 byte values and then join to this table.

Comment: Thanks mitch, I will give it a try and let you know how I go.